# Accessing all records as List from Dataset in Structured Streaming

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Spark/Structured Stream. The application is a batch job which will be start once a day and should read all the messages available on Kafka Topic at that point of time, do processing on the messages and write to a text file.

I have the below code which reads from Topic and dumps the contents to a text file.

```
Dataset dataset = sparkSession.readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "TestTopic")
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .load();

dataset = dataset.select(from_json(col("value").cast(DataTypes.StringType),schema).as("record")).selectExpr("record" + ".*");

StreamingQuery streamingQuery = dataset.writeStream()
        .format("csv")
        .option("sep", "#")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "path/to/checkpoint/dir")
        .start("/output");

streamingQuery.processAllAvailable();
```

The application already has all the processing/enrichment/business validation/logic as Spring components and those components expects a List<Bean>.

Questions:

1. Can I use Spring components within the transformations ? How ?
2. Is there a way to get access to all records at once so that I can create a List and pass it to  the Spring components. The map/ForeachWriter provides access to one record at a time.
3. Some of the Spring components access rest services, if those service are down I want to terminate the structured streaming and not commit the offsets to Kafka, so that when the service becomes available, the streaming job can be started again.